# What components would I need to capture high resolution images mounted on a 5 inch drone (not FPV images)?

Tags: video-transmitters, building, fpv-cameras, camera

I have built my own 5 inch drone using a Mateksys f722 controller and INAV, but I'm confused on what components I need to make an image capture interface similar to the DJI drones. For example, the mavic air has a 12 MP camera and 85 degrees FOV and you can see the camera's feed from the drone when you capture the image. To use an FPV camera like foxteer or runcam, I think I need a separate vtx board for my controller, but the image quality on those FPV cameras doesn't seem very good. Should I just get a wifi camera and mount it on the drone? Is that a typical approach? My end goal is to be able to see the live images from the drone before I save one to a disk.